# Error in installing ctc 4

Tags: websphere-portal

When i tried installing ctc4 on wp8, the following is displayed in cmd.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile>ctc-install

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile>rem (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2010, 2011.

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile>rem Batch file to install CTC
"Loaded ctc.properties file"
"PAA Path resolved to C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WEBSPH~1\WP_PRO~1\paa\ctc.paa"
passed -properties C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WEBSPH~1\WP_PRO~1\ctc.properties
"using C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WEBSPH~1\WP_PRO~1\ctc.properties file"
"Properties set"
"PAA Path resolved to C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WEBSPH~1\WP_PRO~1\SITE-B~1\paa\site-builder.paa"
"Running install-paa -DPAALocation=C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WEBSPH~1\WP_PRO~1\SITE-B~1\paa\site-builder.
paa -DappName=wp.ctc.nswiz -DofflineMode=true -Dcomponents/wp.ctc.nswiz.app=true -Dcomponents/w
p.ctc.nswiz.appcontent=true -Dcomponents/wp.ctc.nswiz.apppage.base=true -Dcomponents/wp.ctc.nsw
iz.appcontent.blank=false -Dcomponents/wp.ctc.nswiz.apppage.virtual=false     -DFAILURE_LOG_DIR
=C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\WEBSPH~1\WP_PRO~1\SITE-B~1"
**'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
operable program or batch file.
ctc.properties
**\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\paa\wp.ctc was unexpected at this time.**
```

I don't know how to solve this. Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is that install Portal in a location without spaces in between(ie : C:\IBM\WebSphere\PortalServer) .Also,in your ctc.properties , enter the PROFILE_DIR path in quotes "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile"

Comment: Also,CTC4 can be installed only on WebSphere Portal Server 8.0.0.1 or higher.

Comment: But vinoo, how can i install the portal again? Won't it be a long running task and all my saved contents may get lost in the process.

Comment: Vijay,try modifying in ctc.properties , the PROFILE_DIR path in quotes "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile" and see whether that solves the issue